# Point on elliptic curve that is torsion over algebraic closure

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, elliptic-curves, cryptography

Say I have an elliptic curve $E: y^2 = x^3+4$ over $\mathbb{F}_{7}$. I want to find an $7$-torsion point in $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_7$ which is not in $\mathbb{F}_7$. How do I do that?

The $n$-torsion points are: $E[n] = \{P\in E(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_7)\mid nP = \infty\}$.

Comment: One way would be to find the appropriate [division polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_polynomials). A possibility may also be to look at the solutions of $[8]P=P$. Multiplying by $8$ amounts to using the point doubling formula thrice.

Comment: Using Hasse-Weil-Davenport it follows (barring a calculation error by me) that the simplest $7$-torsion points have coordinates in $\Bbb{F}_{7^6}$. I would use that as a verification step only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $x$-coordinate $x_0$ of any nontrivial $7$-torsion point over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_7$ is a zero of the $7$th division polynomial $\psi_7$ which is in your case equal to $5\cdot(x^3-2)^7$. Thus the $y$-coordinate $y_0$
of such a point satisfies $y_0^2=x_0^3+4=-1$. Thus any $7$-torsion point over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_7$ is of the form $(x_0,y_0)$ where $x_0$ is a third root of $2$ and $y_0$ is a root of $-1$.
Since the only cubes in $\mathbb{F}_7^*$ are $\pm 1$, the smallest subfield of $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_7$ containing a third root of $2$ is $\mathbb{F}_{7^3}$. Similarly, since $-1$ is not a square, the smallest subfield of $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_7$ containing a root of $-1$ is $\mathbb{F}_{7^2}$. Thus the smallest subfield of $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_7$ over which your curve has a nontrivial $7$-torsion point is $\mathbb{F}_{7^6}$, as predicted by Jyrki Lahtonen.